# Presentation of $S_4$ with $3$ generators and easier relators

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, symmetric-groups

The presentation $$< x^4,y^3,z^2,yxzx^2,zxzy^2x^3,zyzy >$$ for $S_4$ is quite complicated. $S_4$ could be easily generated by $2$ elements, but
I prefer $3$ generators with orders $2,3$ and $4$ because then the elements $x^j\cdot y^k\cdot z^l$ with $0\le j\le 3\ ,\ 0\le k\le 2\ ,\ 0\le l\le 1$ are the group elements.

This is impossible with $2$ generators because the maximum order of an element in $S_4$ is $4$.

In general, $n-1$ generators are sufficient for $S_n$ , if the above property
is required (maybe, less relators suffice for larger $n$, does anyone know the actual minimum ? )

> Is there a presentation of $S_4$ with $3$ generators and easier relators ?
>   The relators must determine $S_4$ uniquely. It would be best, if the presentation could be generalized for $S_n$ and $n-1$ generators.

Comment: $\langle x,y,z \mid x^2=y^3=(xy)^4=xyz=1 \rangle$.

Comment: @Derek sure, go ahead and give a way easier presentation! Is there one for general $S_n$?

Comment: I am not aware of anything corresponding to this for $S_n$. I believe that there are known presentations on $2$ generators with a fixed number of relations, but they are complicated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\langle x,y,z \mid x^2=y^3=z^4=xyz=1 \rangle$ is a nice presentation of $S_4$ on three generators. I don't know anything equivalent for $S_n$ - probably the Coxeter presentation described by Matt Samuel is the "nicest".

Many people were surprised when it was proved that there exist are presentations of $S_n$ on two generators and a fixed number of relations. See, for example [here](https://www.math.auckland.ac.nz/~conder/preprints/SymGpPresentations.pdf), where such a presentation is described with at most $123$ relations, for all $n$. You woudl not describe these as nice presentations, but they are useful in computational applications.

It has now been proved that all finite simple groups, with the possible exception of the Ree groups $^2G_2(3^{2k+1})$ have presentations on two geenrators and a bounded number of relators.

Answer (score 9):

You could use the Coxeter generators, $s_1=(12)$, $s_2=(23)$, $s_3=(34)$. Then the relations are
$$s_1^2=s_2^2=s_3^2=(s_1s_2)^3=(s_2s_3)^3=(s_1s_3)^2=1$$
This generalizes similarly to $S_n$,
$$s_i^2=1$$
$$(s_is_{i+1})^3=1$$
$$(s_is_j)^2=1$$
if $|i-j|>1$.

This can be made to satisfy the element order condition by using the generators $s_1s_2\cdots s_k$ instead, which are the cycles $(12\ldots k)$. Modify the relations accordingly.

Comment: @Peter done. Sorry it's not pretty but I'm doing this on mobile.

Comment: @Peter you could replace $s_3$ with $(1234)$ to get the desired orders of the elements, but I'd have to think about what the relations would be.

Comment: @Peter and $s_2$ with $s_1s_2$.

Comment: So, $s_2=(312)$ ? By the way, the above relators work for $x=(1234),y=(123),z=(12)$

Comment: @Peter actually $(123)$. We may have a pattern here.

Comment: @Peter all the cycles $(12\ldots k)$, but it's seriously redundant because the first and the last generate the whole group anyway. It does satisfy the condition though.