Prove that $S_4/K \cong S_3$ using the fundamental theorem on homomorphism.
Let $A$ be the set formed by the elements of Klein group but identity, A= { (1,2)(3,4);(1,3)(2,4);(1,4)(2,3)}. Consider the set $Big(A)$ of bijection from A to itseld. With the operation of composition it is a group isomorphic to $S3$. Let $f:S_4 \rightarrow Big(A)$ where for every $\sigma$, $f(\sigma)$ is such that for every $x \in A$ $f(\sigma)(x)=\sigma x \sigma^{-1}$. Prove that $f$ is a group homomorphism and $S_4/K \cong S_3$ using the fundamental theorem on homomorphism.

$f$ is an homomorphism:
Let $\sigma$ and $\tau \in S_4$ then $f(\sigma\tau)(x) = (\sigma\tau)x(\sigma\tau)^{-1}=\sigma\tau x\tau^{-1}\sigma^{-1}=f(\sigma)f(\tau)x$.

2)If I can prove that f is surjective, then since $Kerf$ is a normal soubroup of $S_4$, we have $S_4/{kerf} \cong S_3$(fundamental theorem),from which follows that the cardinality of $kerf$ is 4. Furhtermore, we can easily see that $K$(the Klein group) is included int the kernel,which therefore corresponds exactly to $K$ due to  cardinality reasons.
How can I prove that $f$ is surjective? Anyone knows another way to prove that $S_4/K \cong S_3$ using the fundamental theorem on homomorphism?

$A$ is a set of size $4$, so will have $24$ self-bijections.  How can this be isomorphic to $S_3$?  Did you mean $S_4$?

A is a set of 3 elements, I'm sorry there was writing mistake.

One way to do it is using a presentation like $S_4 = \langle x, y, z\ |\ xx = yyy = zzzz = xyz = 1 \rangle.$ Just send $x$ to a transposition, $y$ to a $3$-cycle and  $z$ to their product, which is another transposition. But I'm not sure if this what you want. (See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1658356/1042867 for the presentation.)

Note that $zz$ is an element of $K$ that maps to $1.$ Since the kernel must be a normal subgroup, the kernel must contain all $K$. The map is surjective and so by a size argument the kernel is exactly $K.$

By the way, I have reviewed your method and I think it's right and simpler, even if I don't think that's a standard notation. $f$ is surjective because when applied to $(2,3)$ it interchanges the first $2$ elements of $A$ and when applied to $(1,2)$ it interchanges the last two elements of $A.$ The two resulting transpositions generate $Big(A) \cong S3.$

I'm sorry but (2,3) and (1,2) aren't elements of $A$, I edited the post maybe now it's clearer.

I mean $f(2\ 3)$ is a transposition of elements of $A.$ So I'm only using $(2\ 3) \in S4$

If $A$ is the conjugacy class of the permutations of type $(2,2)$, i.e. $A= \{(12)(34),(13)(24),(14)(23)\}$ then the action of $S_4$ on $A$ gives a homomorphism $v\colon S_4 \to \mathrm{Sym}(A)\cong S_3$. Now by the orbit-stabilizer theorem, if $\sigma \in A$ we must have $Z_{\sigma}:=Z_{S_4}(\sigma)$ has $|Z_{\sigma}|=8$. Since $K_4 = \{e\}\cup A$ is abelian, we must have $K_4 \lhd Z_{\sigma}$ for all $\sigma \in A$, so that $Z_{\sigma}$ has (at least) 3 elements of order $2$.
This in fact implies that $Z_{\sigma} \cong D_8$ the dihedral group of order $8$,and since $|Z(D_8)|=2$, it follows that $\{\sigma\} = A\cap Z(Z_{\sigma})$, that is, $Z_{\sigma}$ determines $\sigma$ as its unique nontrivial central element. It follows that the $\{Z_{\sigma}: \sigma\in A\}$ are pairwise distinct, and hence their intersection must be a proper subgroup of each. But we already noted that $K_4\subseteq \bigcap_{\sigma \in A} Z_{\sigma}$ and so we must have $\bigcap_{\sigma \in A}Z_{\sigma} = K_4$.
Since this intersection is precisely the kernel of the action map $v$ it follows that $v$ induces an injective homomorphism $\bar{V}\colon S_3/K_4 \to \mathrm{Sym}(A)$ and hence since its domain and codomain both have order $6$ it is an isomorphism as required.
Addendum: One can also see that $Z_{\sigma} \cong D_8$ more conceptually as follows: If $S$ is a square, then labelling the vertices of $S$ with the numbers $\{1,2,3,4\}$ we obtain a map $c\colon D_8 \to S_4$ from the symmetry group of the square to $S_4$ by considering the action of $D_8$ on the labelled vertices. Since the location of the vertices determines that of every point in the square, the homomorphism $c$ is an embedding. Now the rotation by $\pi$ is the unique nontrivial central element of $D_8$, and it is easy to see that it has type $(2,2)$. For example, if we label the vertices of $S$ as follows:
$$
\begin{array}{ccc}1 & - & 2 \\
| & & |\\ 4 & - & 3 \end{array}
$$
then the permutation $(13)(24)$ corresponds the symmetry given by rotating by $\pi$.
This in fact gives an alternative way to establish the isomorphism: note that the symmetries of $S$ which correspond to $A$ are the rotation by $\pi$ and the two reflections about the lines through the midpoints of opposite sides. These two reflections are conjugate in $D_8$, and so for $\sigma\in A$, there is an element of $Z_{\sigma}$ which swaps the other two elements of $A$. Thus the image of $v\colon S_4 \to \mathrm{Sym}(A)$ contains all transpositions, and since these generate $S_3$, $v$ must be surjective, and hence its kernel must have order $4$, and hence $K_4=\ker(V)$ (since it is clear that $K_4\subseteq \ker(V)$).
